# FTS3 SQLite database query's

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to implement a search in my application, but if I want to query the application force closes with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I know it indicates, that something is not initialized. But I cant figure out what.

First of all, my Database:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_FTS 
+ " USING fts3(" + COL_ID + ", " + COL_KEY_NAME + ", "
+ COL_KEY_1+ " , " + COL_KEY_3 + ", " + COL_KEY_3 + " " + ");");
```

and filled with example sets:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_FTS + " (data1, data2, data3, data4) VALUES ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_FTS + " (data1, data2, data3, data4) VALUES ('Test1_2', 'Test2_2', 'Test3_2', 'Test4_2')");
```

My activity is rather simple, initiate anything, catch the search Intent and do the query.

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Activity is in singleTop mode and I use this method to catch Intent and query string: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle

*Now I used different query ways:*

first of all, simple cursor:

```
public Cursor sampleQuery(String query) {
    tmp = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FTS + " WHERE data1 MATCH '" + query + "'";
    return database.rawQuery(tmp, null);
}
```

**get me an FC.**

Tried another:

```
   public Cursor queryFTS(String query) {
        assert !TextUtils.isEmpty(query) : "query must not be an empty string!";

        return database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_FTS,
                new String[] { DatabaseHelper.COL_KEY_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COL_KEY_WEBURL, DatabaseHelper.COL_KEY_STREAMURL, DatabaseHelper.COL_ID },
                DatabaseHelper.TABLE_FTS + " MATCH ?",
                new String[] { appendWildcard(query) },
                null, null, null);
    }

    private String appendWildcard(String query) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) return query;

        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        final String[] splits = TextUtils.split(query, " ");

        for (String split : splits)
          builder.append(split).append("*").append(" ");

        return builder.toString().trim();
    }
```

**and get an FC, too.**

I don't saved the stacktrace, but I remind me, the traces are alway show me the code where my query get returned and executed. Which does I do wrong?

**Stacktrace:**

> 01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>   ComponentInfo{de.arvidg.onlineradio/de.arvidg.onlineradio.SearchActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-25 22:02:20.324:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
>  01-25
>   22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>  01-25
>   22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>  01-25 22:02:20.324:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>  01-25
>   22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>  01-25
>   22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>  01-25 22:02:20.324:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>  01-25
>   22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>  01-25 22:02:20.324:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5025): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   **de.arvidg.test.SearchActivity.sampleQuery(SearchActivity.java:81)
>
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   de.arvidg.test.SearchActivity.doSearch(SearchActivity.java:76)
>
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   de.arvidg.test.SearchActivity.handleIntent(SearchActivity.java:62)
>
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   de.arvidg.test.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:37)**
>
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>  01-25
>   22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   01-25 22:02:20.324: E/AndroidRuntime(5025):   ... 11 more

Line 81:

```
public Cursor sampleQuery(String query) {
    String tmp = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_FTS + " WHERE data1 MATCH '" + query + "'";
    return database.rawQuery(tmp, null); **<--- Line 81**
}
```

the other line are only backtracked from intent to line 81 (means, nothing special there ^^)

Comment: Stack trace and full code may help. It is hard predict from half information. But, my guess is 'database' in queries is null.

Comment: Yup, stack traces are pretty much required when debugging FC:s.

Comment: Thats exactly what I think, too. But why is it null? I initiated it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! The Database was not initiatet correct.

It was in the onCreate Method. Added it to my search method solved it.